How to use ngCspNonce in Angular
I am trying to use a nonce in my Content Security Policy in an Angular app.
My content security policy includes:
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-blahblah'

And a simplified version of my index.html:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="/">
  <script nonce="blahblah" type="text/javascript">console.log("hello!");</script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root ngCspNonce="blahblah"></app-root>
</body>
</html>

The simple script with the "hello!" print works fine.  My understanding was that the ngCspNonce attribute would be added to the other script tags that Angular generates.  However when I serve my site, this is the page source in my browser:

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-critters-container="">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="/">
  <script nonce="blahblah" type="text/javascript">console.log("hello!");</script>
  <style nonce="blahblah">@charset "UTF-8";:root{--bs-blue:#0d6efd;--bs-indigo:#6610f2;--bs-purple:#6f42c1;--bs-pink:#d63384;--bs-red:#dc3545;--bs-orange:#fd7e14;--bs-yellow:#ffc107;--bs-green:#198754;--bs-teal:#20c997;--bs-cyan:#0dcaf0;--bs-black:#000;--bs-white:#fff;--bs-gray:#6c757d;--bs-gray-dark:#343a40;--bs-gray-100:#f8f9fa;--bs-gray-200:#e9ecef;--bs-gray-300:#dee2e6;--bs-gray-400:#ced4da;--bs-gray-500:#adb5bd;--bs-gray-600:#6c757d;--bs-gray-700:#495057;--bs-gray-800:#343a40;--bs-gray-900:#212529;--bs-primary:#2d2d2d;--bs-secondary:#6c757d;--bs-success:#198754;--bs-info:#0dcaf0;--bs-warning:#ffc107;--bs-danger:#dc3545;--bs-light:#f8f9fa;--bs-dark:#212529;--bs-primary-rgb:45, 45, 45;--bs-secondary-rgb:108, 117, 125;--bs-success-rgb:25, 135, 84;--bs-info-rgb:13, 202, 240;--bs-warning-rgb:255, 193, 7;--bs-danger-rgb:220, 53, 69;--bs-light-rgb:248, 249, 250;--bs-dark-rgb:33, 37, 41;--bs-primary-text-emphasis:#121212;--bs-secondary-text-emphasis:#2b2f32;--bs-success-text-emphasis:#0a3622;--bs-info-text-emphasis:#055160;--bs-warning-text-emphasis:#664d03;--bs-danger-text-emphasis:#58151c;--bs-light-text-emphasis:#495057;--bs-dark-text-emphasis:#495057;--bs-primary-bg-subtle:#d5d5d5;--bs-secondary-bg-subtle:#e2e3e5;--bs-success-bg-subtle:#d1e7dd;--bs-info-bg-subtle:#cff4fc;--bs-warning-bg-subtle:#fff3cd;--bs-danger-bg-subtle:#f8d7da;--bs-light-bg-subtle:#fcfcfd;--bs-dark-bg-subtle:#ced4da;--bs-primary-border-subtle:#ababab;--bs-secondary-border-subtle:#c4c8cb;--bs-success-border-subtle:#a3cfbb;--bs-info-border-subtle:#9eeaf9;--bs-warning-border-subtle:#ffe69c;--bs-danger-border-subtle:#f1aeb5;--bs-light-border-subtle:#e9ecef;--bs-dark-border-subtle:#adb5bd;--bs-white-rgb:255, 255, 255;--bs-black-rgb:0, 0, 0;--bs-font-sans-serif:system-ui, -apple-system, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", "Noto Sans", "Liberation Sans", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";--bs-font-monospace:SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;--bs-gradient:linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));--bs-body-font-family:var(--bs-font-sans-serif);--bs-body-font-size:1rem;--bs-body-font-weight:400;--bs-body-line-height:1.5;--bs-body-color:#212529;--bs-body-color-rgb:33, 37, 41;--bs-body-bg:#fff;--bs-body-bg-rgb:255, 255, 255;--bs-emphasis-color:#000;--bs-emphasis-color-rgb:0, 0, 0;--bs-secondary-color:rgba(33, 37, 41, .75);--bs-secondary-color-rgb:33, 37, 41;--bs-secondary-bg:#e9ecef;--bs-secondary-bg-rgb:233, 236, 239;--bs-tertiary-color:rgba(33, 37, 41, .5);--bs-tertiary-color-rgb:33, 37, 41;--bs-tertiary-bg:#f8f9fa;--bs-tertiary-bg-rgb:248, 249, 250;--bs-heading-color:inherit;--bs-link-color:#007bff;--bs-link-color-rgb:0, 123, 255;--bs-link-decoration:underline;--bs-link-hover-color:#0062cc;--bs-link-hover-color-rgb:0, 98, 204;--bs-code-color:#d63384;--bs-highlight-color:#212529;--bs-highlight-bg:#fff3cd;--bs-border-width:1px;--bs-border-style:solid;--bs-border-color:#dee2e6;--bs-border-color-translucent:rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);--bs-border-radius:.375rem;--bs-border-radius-sm:.25rem;--bs-border-radius-lg:.5rem;--bs-border-radius-xl:1rem;--bs-border-radius-xxl:2rem;--bs-border-radius-2xl:var(--bs-border-radius-xxl);--bs-border-radius-pill:50rem;--bs-box-shadow:0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);--bs-box-shadow-sm:0 .125rem .25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);--bs-box-shadow-lg:0 1rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);--bs-box-shadow-inset:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);--bs-focus-ring-width:.25rem;--bs-focus-ring-opacity:.25;--bs-focus-ring-color:rgba(45, 45, 45, .25);--bs-form-valid-color:#198754;--bs-form-valid-border-color:#198754;--bs-form-invalid-color:#dc3545;--bs-form-invalid-border-color:#dc3545}*,*:before,*:after{box-sizing:border-box}body{margin:0;font-family:var(--bs-body-font-family);font-size:var(--bs-body-font-size);font-weight:var(--bs-body-font-weight);line-height:var(--bs-body-line-height);color:var(--bs-body-color);text-align:var(--bs-body-text-align);background-color:var(--bs-body-bg);-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)}:root{--bs-breakpoint-xs:0;--bs-breakpoint-sm:576px;--bs-breakpoint-md:768px;--bs-breakpoint-lg:992px;--bs-breakpoint-xl:1200px;--bs-breakpoint-xxl:1400px}html{overflow-x:hidden;font-size:14px}</style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.09ca5b46bf96a485.css" media="print" ngcspmedia="all"><noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.09ca5b46bf96a485.css"></noscript>
  <script nonce="blahblah">(() => {
  const children = document.head.children;
  function onLoad() {this.media = this.getAttribute('ngCspMedia');}
  for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    const child = children[i];
    child.hasAttribute('ngCspMedia') && child.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
  }
})();</script></head>
<body>
  <app-root ngcspnonce="blahblah"></app-root>
  <script src="runtime.6791e51006df24ff.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="polyfills.2149b2c3f7920599.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="scripts.3e75d50128144df1.js" defer=""></script>
  <script src="main.9328a66c7aa91680.js" type="module"></script></body>
</html>

I can see that the nonce has added to the script tag that Angular inserted in the head, but not the scripts in the body (runtime.6791e51006df24ff.js, etc), so I get CSP errors when loading those scripts.
How can I get the nonce added to those also?

I did find this issue which seems to indicate it's a known deficiency in Angular.

The Angular issue that causes this is supposedly fixed in version 19, but for now I'm on version 18.
I used this blatant hack as a workaround, doing a search and replace when the HTML file is served.
The relevant parts of my index.html:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>    
  <script nonce="CSP_NONCE_PLACEHOLDER" type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>    
  <app-root ngCspNonce="CSP_NONCE_PLACEHOLDER"></app-root>
</body> 
</html> 
                                                                

And in my express server:
  // generate CSP nonce
  app.use((_req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.cspNonce = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
    next();
  });


  let indexSrcText = fs.readFileSync(`${distDir}/index.html`).toString();                                                     
      
  app.get("/*", (req, res, next) => {
    let suffixes = ['.html', '.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.svg', '.mp4', '.ico', '.json', '.js', '.css' ];                       
    if (!suffixes.some(o => req.url.endsWith(o))) {                                                                           
          
      // set CSP nonce in index.html
      let indexText = indexSrcText.replace(new RegExp('CSP_NONCE_PLACEHOLDER', 'g'), res.locals.cspNonce);                    
          
      res.send(indexText);                                                                                                    
    }
    else {
      next();                                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                         
  });                                                                                                                         
      


To include the nonce, you have to do two things:

Add a nonce-$VALUE setting to the style-src section of the CSP.
Add an ngCspNonce attribute to the root element of your application (this is where the Angular Runtime picks it up). You have to set the content of this attribute to the same $VALUE you use in the CSP.

Your applications index.html looks roughly like this
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Application Title</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none';
    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  </head>

  <body>
      <app-root></app-root>
  </body>

</html>


Right... I have done all that.  As I described in the question, the issue is that Angular is only adding the nonce to the script elements in the head, not those that Angular adds to the body.

What is added in index.html file here? I don't see anything related to nonce.
